# heroku run rake db:migrate fails with "cannot load such file -- debugger"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I'm getting this weird error when I try to migrate my database. Does anyone know what's going on?

There are no `require debugger` calls in any of my migrations. I do have some in another rake task that's not a migration, though. Is it possible that that's the problem?

```
me$ heroku run rake db:migrate --trace


Running `rake db:migrate --trace` attached to terminal... up, run.2463
rake aborted!
cannot load such file -- debugger
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `block in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
/app/lib/tasks/misc.rake:6:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:222:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:222:in `block in load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:222:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:641:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:641:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:641:in `run_tasks_blocks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:244:in `run_tasks_blocks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:446:in `load_tasks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/app/Rakefile:6:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rake/application.rb:637:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in load_rakefile'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rake/application.rb:93:in `load_rakefile'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rake/application.rb:77:in `block in run'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/app/bin/rake:4:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, ok. Figured it out.  One my other rake tasks had `require debugger` in its root scope. That's what was throwing heroku off. Problem solved.